# Variance of Linear Combination of Independent vs. Dependent Variables

Tags: statistics, variance, covariance

Is the variance of a linear combination of independent variables always less than or equal to the variance of the same linear combination of dependent variables?

I.e. in general

$Var(\sum_i a_i X_i)=\sum_ia_i^2 var(X_i)+2\sum_{j>i}a_i a_j cov(X_i, X_j) $

If $X_i$ are independent the second term is 0. If dependent, is the second term positive definite? I believe so, but am unable to prove it. Thanks!

Edit: See drhab's response below. Its a great counterexample to the question as asked. However, suppose I add a constraint such that $\sum_i a_i X_i>0$. I.e. we rule out the case given in his response below. Is the second term now positive definite? If not is there some constraint that will make this so?

I'll update if I find the answer myself.

Comment: Let it be that rv $X$ only takes values in  $[1,2]$. Then take  $X_1=X$ and $X_2=2-X$ so that  $X_1+X_2=2>0$. Nevertheless again  $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=-\mathsf{Var}X<0$ as in my answer below so the proposed constraint does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The second term can be negative as well.

E.g. let it be that $X$ is a non-degenerated rv with $\mathbb EX^2<\infty$.

Further let $X_1=X$ and $X_2=-X$ and let $X_1,X_3$ be independent where $X_3$ has the same distribution as $X$.

We find $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=-\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)=-\mathsf{Var}(X)<0$.

In that case we find: $$\mathsf{Var}(X_1+X_2)=0<\mathsf{Var}X_1+\mathsf{Var}X_3$$

Comment: Thanks! This is a good example. There's a physics problem I'm trying to solve that's behind this question and your example made me realize I have a constraint that rules out this particular case. I'm thinking about how to phrase it simply as purely a math problem and will edit my question if I'm still stuck. If I figure it out I'll just mark this as the correct answer since its a great counterexample for the question as asked. Thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome.